# Characterization of multipliers on the Dirichlet space of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Can someone tell me whether there is a characterization of boundedness of multiplication operators on the [Dirichlet space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_space)   of the unit disc? These are holomorphic functions $f$  on the unit disk $D$ such that $$\iint_D |f'|^2<\infty$$

For the Hardy space, the multipliers are precisely the bounded analytic functions on the disc. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the multipliers of the Dirichlet space are not as easy to describe as of Hardy and Bergman spaces. The characterization was obtained by  Stegenga in  [Multipliers of the Dirichlet space](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256047800) (free access). In addition to boundedness, it requires a Carleson-type condition in terms of capacity: 
$$
\iint_{\bigcup S(I_j)} |f'|^2 \le A \operatorname{cap}(\bigcup I_j)
$$
for all finite disjoint collections of subarcs $I_j$ of the unit circle.

Some easy-to-verify sufficient conditions were subsequently obtained 
 [Univalent multipliers of the Dirichlet space](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029003133) by Axler and Shields.